# How to Detect and extract QR code from a preview frame using OpenCV in Android?

Tags: android, qr-code

I am using Android Zxing library to decode a QR code, that has to be extracted in real time from a camera preview frame. The problem is that I have to use OpenCV to do the QR code detection, without asking the user to capture the image. Can anybody please tell me:
How to use frames from a camera?
**How to use OpenCV to do QR detection on these frames, without capturing the image?
What algorithm to use for QR code detection?**
Also, I would appreciate if somebody can tell me what functions, libraries to use, as well as some sample codes that may help me.

Update: This is what I am doing now:
Using a preview frame, decoding it to Byte array, and then passing it to RGBLuminance
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

```
    // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
    // to draw.

    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);

        camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                boolean shouldCall = (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime) > 1000;
                if (shouldCall) {
                    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    //slow work


                Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize();

                Bitmap bMap1 =  BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
                TextView textv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytext);
                LuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(bMap1); 

                BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
                Reader reader = new MultiFormatReader();

                try {
                     Result result = reader.decode(bitmap);
                     text = result.getText(); 
                        byte[] rawBytes = result.getRawBytes();
                        if (rawBytes!= null)
                            camera.stopPreview();
                        BarcodeFormat format = result.getBarcodeFormat(); 
                        ResultPoint[] points = result.getResultPoints();
                        ParsedResult result2 = parseResult(result);

                        textv.setText(text);



                } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                    camera.startPreview();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ChecksumException e) {
                    text = "Checksum Error";
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (FormatException e) {
                    text = "Format Error";
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();


                } 

                lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }



            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        camera.startPreview();
    }
}
```

But this isn't working. Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong? Also, I am using the same decoding instance in my other code snippet, where I simply take a picture and decode it. But every time the picture doesn't contain a QR, the app crashes with a force close. What do I do about that? Somebody please help

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if you are using zxing already then you already have code that decodes QR codes from camera frames in Android, full stop. What else do you need -- why bother with OpenCV?

Comment: it has to be detected. I cannot use an image file. As I mentioned, I have to use camera preview frames in order to detect the code. This is where OpenCV comes in.

Comment: Yes, and as I said, the library does not have to decode an image file. In fact it includes code that detect the barcode from the camera preview frame (not a photo). If you have to use OpenCV for some reason, OK, but if you don't, you already have a complete solution in your hands.